# CSS Dropdown menu and jquery chosen and z-index

Tags: css, overlay, z-index, jquery-chosen

I'm having problems with where to place the z-index css code and plugin chosen for jquery.

My dropdown menu is on top of all the content as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9JE5/3/

My HTML Code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="chznselect">
    <select class="chz-select" name="example">
        <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="3">Value 3</option>
        <option value="4">Value 4</option>
        <option value="5">Value 5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I've tried to add the z-index code everywhere but it just doesn't seem to work for me.

Hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element's z-index is only relevant to other elements within the same stacking context.

From [MDN's stacking context doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context):

> on mobile WebKit and Chrome 22+, position: fixed always creates a new
>   stacking context, even when z-index is "auto"

In other words, since `header` has `position:fixed`, its children are in a different stacking context than elements outside of `header` (like your `chznselect` element).

However, `header` itself is in the same stacking context as `chznselect`. Since you gave `chznselect` a z-index greater than 0 without specifying a z-index for `header` (ie. its z-index is auto), `chznselect` will always display on top of `header` and all its child elements.

Here's an updated version of your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9JE5/4/) in which I gave `header` a z-index greater than `chznselect`--it looks like it's working as intended now.